# Migrating System.Reflection.Emit code that uses TypeToken to .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, cil

I'm attempting to migrate some `Reflection.Emit` code to .NET Core.  The code generates a static constructor that references the type being (static) constructed, something like this:

```
ConstructorBuilder typeInitializer = typeBuilder.DefineTypeInitializer();
ILGenerator typeInitializerIL = typeInitializer.GetILGenerator();
typeInitializerIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeBuilder.TypeToken.Token);
typeInitializerIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle", new Type[] { typeof(RuntimeTypeHandle) });
typeInitializerIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, MyClass.DoSomethingWithRuntimeType_MethodInfo);
```

Unfortunately, The .NET Core version of `TypeBuilder` doesn't appear to support the `TypeToken` property.  I don't actually need the `TypeToken`, but I *do* need to use the `Type` instance in the generated constructor.  I've already determined using a sample class that .NET Core does actually generate the CIL I want (at least from source code in VS), but how do I get `Reflection.Emit` to generate the correct CIL for this situation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtypeinfo?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Emit_TypeBuilder_CreateTypeInfo

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not seeing how that helps?  I know how to access the `TypeInfo` for the type I'm in the process of generating...I need to access its `Type` in the code for that type's static constructor, which I'm trying to generate on-the-fly.

Comment: TypeInfo.AsType() provides the type you want.

Comment: @HansPassant That helps me get the Type to use in the code above, but not in the code that it's generating (which is where I need it).  I can't pass non-literal data to the code being generated because that data exists when the code is being generated, but not when the code is running.  The type generator instance the `TypeInfo` is coming from *doesn't exist* when that code is being run.